# Play 360° videos on GearVR without going through the Oculus interface

Tags: android, oculus, gear-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I'd like to know if there is any way to play a 360° video on the GearVR without going through the Oculus interface. What I mean is, I just want an icon on my phone that I can click and it launches the video. Then I just have to plug the GearVR to watch it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in creating an application, then you could use the Samsung Gear VR Framework to develop the application for this. Please see the below link:
https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos/tree/master/gvr-360video
This app plays a video in 360 when the app is launched.